# Why templates include file doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I'm learning how to use templatesjs from:
[https://www.npmjs.com/package/templatesjs](http://templatesjs)

They have an example of using include html file in other html file (using `<%include%>` tag)

When I'm trying to build my own example, it doesn't work (The screen is empty, with no errors):

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var fs = require('fs');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json())
var templatesjs = require('templatesjs');

// FILES
var MAIN_FILE = '/main.html';


/* 
 *  Home page
 */
app.get('/', function (req, res) {

   fs.readFile(__dirname + MAIN_FILE, function(err,data){   
        if(err) throw err;

        templatesjs.set(data, function(err,data){
            if(err) throw err;
            res.send();               
        });
    });  

})


/* 
 *  Startup
 */
var server = app.listen(8082, function () {
   var host = server.address().address
   var port = server.address().port

   // start
   console.log("App listening at http://%s:%s", host, port)
})
```

the main html.file looks:

```
<html>
<title> Tutorial -> Templates Js Server </title>
<head>

</head>
<body>

    <div> 
        <%include Top.html%>
    </div>
    <div> 
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and Top.html file looks:

```
<p>TOP</p>
```

(I have tried to add `<html>` tag into Top.html,  but same results);

The problem is that the web screen I'm getting is empty (with no errors at Node.js)

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: First of all, why do you use that node package? It seems that it's not a famous and strong module, use [Pug](https://pugjs.org/api/getting-started.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you doesn't send back any data to incoming request! your `res.send()` is empty. you should send something back if you really want to show it. for example: `res.send('hello world')`.

If you want to render your template with your data, you could use `templatesjs.renderAll()` method to populate your html template with desired data as follows:

```
// set default directory for html partials
templatesjs.dir = "./public/partials/";

app.get('/', function(req, res) {

  fs.readFile(__dirname + MAIN_FILE, function(err, data) {
    if (err) throw err;


    templatesjs.set(data, function(err, data) {
      if (err) throw err;

      var list = { // this is your data
        name: 'your name'
      }; 

      templatesjs.renderAll(list, function(err, data) {
        if (err) throw err;
        res.send(data);
      });
    });
  });

})
```

Top.html:

```
<p>Hello, my name is <%name%></p>
```

and this file should reside in `./public/partials/` directory as we set default include directory to this path;